# Como usar um loadData da webview mas manter os dados anteriores na tela?

Tags: java, webview

Há alguma forma de fazer isso? Eu estou fazendo um app de chatbot, mas toda vez que eu uso o loadData os dados que aparecem sobrescrevem os anteriores, gostaria de deixar todos na tela...